# Will ASP.NET Form Get value from Barcode

Tags: asp.net, barcode

ASP.NET Form.  If running a form in a browser on a small (Android) device with a barcode scanner, will the scanned barcode go into the ASP.NET textbox?  Or I need to add something to the application?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it going to depend on which of the 150+ barcode scanners you decide to grab from google play.

However, the answer is yes, or no. It will depend on the kind of scanner.

If you download just a scanning application (software based - not built in scanner).
The reason is Android (and even iOS) don't allow one application to set focus, get/grab/take data from other applications. Nor is the reverse allowed. If that was possible, then the app could also get/grab/take values from when you are say running your on-line banking application.

I don't think Android thus supports focus to another application during scan that has focus. Now if this is factory supplied software on the phone? Then yes, this works like a desktop keyboard "wedge". That means the program does not know if you are typing from keyboard, or input is from the scanner (hence the name keyboard wedge). These will work with a web form.

However, we now seeing the rise of software based keyboard wedges. That means the software scanner is installed on android as a custom keyboard. And this in case, then once again, it will work in a web form.

So, for devices with a built in scanner? yes, that will work in all applications. For a software only (uses built in camera), then again, this is possible if the software in question works as a keyboard/wedge scanner.

If you going to adopt android scanning? then use a purpose built Android scanner.

And another possible if you want to use a software scanner? Write a small android application and have it talk to your web site. This I think is the best solution, but of course means you have to adopt some Android dev tools.

So how this works will depend on if the android device has a built in scanner, or it is a software + camera based scanner. However, it would seem that even now installable software based scanners in theory can be made to work for any application since the application is running and behaving as a user installed keyboard.

So, you have to check the particular device. The answer is not in all cases, and the answer depends on if you using a Android device with a built in scanner, or you looking to use any Android phone as that scanner.

Comment: Albert, thank you for your detailed post.  The device the customer is buying has an integrated barcode scanner.  Hopefully it works as a keyboard wedge,   I will find out soon.